# Time module and file changes

Tags: python

I need to write a script that does the following

Write a python script to list all of the files and directories in the current directory and all subdirectories that have been modified in the last X minutes.
X should be taken in as a command-line argument.
Check that this argument exists, and exit with a suitable error message if it doesn’t.
X should be an int which is less than or equal to 120. If not, exit with a suitable error message.
For each of these files and directories, list the time of modification, whether it is a file or directory,
and its size.

I have come up with this

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import os,sys,time

total = len(sys.argv)

if total < 2:
    print "You need to enter a value in minutes"
    sys.exit()

var =  int(sys.argv[1])


if var < 1 or var > 120 :
    print "The value has to be between 1 and 120"
    sys.exit()
past = time.time() - var * 60

result = []

dir = os.getcwd()


for p, ds, fs in os.walk(dir):
    for fn in fs:
        filepath = os.path.join(p, fn)  
        status = os.stat(filepath).st_mtime
        if os.path.getmtime(filepath) >= past:
            size = os.path.getsize(filepath)
            result.append(filepath)
            created = os.stat(fn).st_mtime 
            asciiTime = time.asctime( time.gmtime( created ) ) 
            print "Files that have changed are %s"%(result)
            print "Size of file is %s"%(size)
```

So it reports back with something like this

```
Files that have changed are ['/home/admin/Python/osglob2.py']
Size of file is 729
Files that have changed are ['/home/admin/Python/osglob2.py', '/home/admin/Python/endswith.py']
Size of file is 285
Files that have changed are ['/home/admin/Python/osglob2.py', '/home/admin/Python/endswith.py', '/home/admin/Python/glob3.py']
Size of file is 633
```

How can i get this to stop reepeating the files ?

Comment: Print your results at the end, not in the middle of your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't clearing your result list at the end of each iteration.  Try something like `result.clear()` after your second `print` statement.  Make sure it is on the same indent as the `for` though, not the `print`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code builds a list of all the files it's encountered is

```
result.append(filepath)
```

and the reason it prints out that whole list every time is

```
print "Files that have changed are %s"%(result)
```

So you will need to change one of those lines: either replace the list, rather than appending to it, or (much more sensible IMO) just print out the one latest filename found, rather than the whole list.

Comment: yeah but i need to print out all the filenames changed in the x minutes, not juts the latest one

Comment: Did you try this and see what it does?

Comment: I moved my print statement under the for loop and it works better now print "Files that have changed are %s , the file sizes are %s and the times modified are %s" % (result,size2,created2) . i dont know how to find out if the modified entry is a file or directory though, any ideas ?

Comment: how do i replace the list ?